# How to get the conditional probabilities from joint probability table?

Tags: conditional-probability, joint-distribution, bayesian-network

I have a table of 3 binary variables whose joint probability is given.

| a | b | c | p(a,b,c) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0.192 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0.144 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0.048 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0.216 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0.192 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0.064 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0.048 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0.096 |

I see that there is a joint probabilities formula for 3 variable

$P(a,b,c) = P(c|a,b)P(a,b) = P(c|a,b)P(b|a)P(a)$

But when I cross-validate it with the table value and the formula it's not exact. What's happening here I am not getting it. It's not the same formula I assume. But how do I get the conditional probabilities from this table? If I can get the form, I can build the DAG.

I can see some patterns like 0.192 and 0.048 is twice even though $a$ is changed. Then I thought maybe $a$ is independent of $b$ and $c$?

I also find this formula $p(θ|X,α)=\frac{p(X|θ)p(θ|α)}{p(X|α)}$

So, I tried with a=1, b=1, c=1,

$
P(c|a, b) * P(b|a) * P(a)
= P(c|a, b) * \frac{P(b \cap a)}{P(a)} * P(a)
= \frac{P(c\cap a \cap b)}{P(a\cap b)} * \frac{P(b \cap a)}{P(a)} * P(a)
= \frac{1}{8}
$

Comment: None of $a,b,c$ are independent of the others.  Can you show use what you got when you tried $P(a,b,c) = P(c\mid a,b)P(a,b) = P(c\mid a,b)P(b\mid a)P(a)$ for some particular value of $a,b,c$?

Comment: The answer to the title question is "apply a definition of conditional probability." For instance, you can compute $P(b\mid a)=P(a\text{ and } b)/P(a)$ and read off the probabilities for any possible values of $(a,b)$ directly from the table.

Comment: @Henry I have added my approach. maybe it's the wrong approach. But the thing I am trying to do is to build that DAG from the formula or vice versa. I am trying to find out how that p(a, b, c) is generated. And also how did you find out none of a, b, or c is independent of each other? I also got the same observation. Just curious about your approach.

Comment: That does not show me your calculations. I would say $\frac23 \times \frac9{25}\times \frac25 = \frac{12}{125}$ not $\frac18$

Comment: @Henry How did you get these values?

Comment: @PritamSinha You first

Comment: @Henry $P(a=1\cap b=1\cap c=1) = \frac{1}{8}$. All other term cancels out. I am getting different answers every time with different approaches.

Comment: The last line of your table says $P(a=1\cap b=1\cap c=1) = 0.096$.  You still have not said how you got  $\frac18$

Comment: @Henry there is 1 occurrence of 111 out of 8 combinations. That's how. How 0.096 is coming that's the thing I want to know

Comment: The $8$ possible combinations are not equally likely: the table shows the joint distribution and so the probability of each

Answer (score 0):

First, It appears that you are mixing up the definition of conditional probability for events and for random variables.

The definition $P(a,b,c)=P(c|a,b)P(a,b)=P(c|a,b)P(b|a)P(a)$ is for events.

For random variables, the definition is :

$$P(A = a,B = b,C =c)=P(C = c|A = a,B = b)P(B = b,A = a)$$

where $a,b,c$ is the values that the random variables $A$, $B$, $C$ can assume (in this case, $0$ or $1$).

Now, if you want  the conditional probability of $C$, given $A$ and $B$, you must obtain the probability $P(B = b,A = a)$.

Here is what you should do:

First, obtain $P(B = b, A = a)$ for all possible values of $a$ and $b$.
For example, to obtain $P(B = 0, A = 1)$, just sum all probabilities where $B = 0$ and $A = 1$. Do the same for the other possible values of $A$ and $B$.

3. Now, you can calculate $P(C = c|A = a,B = b) = \frac{P(A = a,B = b,C =c)}{P(B = b,A = a)}$

you can follow the same reasoning for the other conditional probabilities.

A good exercise for learning is to obtain all possible combinations of conditional and unconditional probabilities for all variables.

Comment: The definitions for random variables and events are the same, it's just a matter of notation. People sometimes do use notation shortcuts like using $P(a)$ meaning $P(A=a)$.

Comment: @Tim. Yes, I understand and agree. Maybe you could help me to rewrite the first sentences in a more precise way, I would appreciate it. A side note:  In my understanding, the OP was confusing about the events definition, for this reason I introduced the random variables. Another possible approach it would be use the notation $a_0$ and $a_1$ to represent, respectively,  the events $\{w \in \Omega: a=0\}$ and $\{w \in \Omega: a=1\}$. But I think this could lead to more confusion.